# Verify a CD/DVD from ISO

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Is there a tool (preferably free) in OS X that will allow me to verify that an ISO was written to a CD or DVD correctly? I want a tool that can do that without going through the burn first.

If there's a tool that can be used from the command line, that's fine too.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices that I can see if you don't want to re-burn and re-verify.

1. Mount the ISO and the DVD and do a recursive diff of the two file systems. For example, if the DVD is `/Volumes/DVD` and the ISO is `/Volumes/ISO` then:

   `diff --recursive /Volumes/DVD /Volumes/ISO`
2. Compare the MD5 sums of all the data on the two images. So:

   `md5 original.iso`

   `dd if=/dev/disk1 bs=2048 count=169383 | md5`

I'd take option #2 over #1 personally, though both are less than great ways to do a comparison.

You could also try exploiting `rsync` to do the comparison instead of using `diff`. If you ran `rsync` with the `--checksum`, `--recursive` and `--dry-run` options what you'd get back is a list of transfers that rsync thinks it needs to make to make the two file trees look the same.

Comment: Thanks! Note for people using option 2: open Disk Utility and unmount the DVD volume first, otherwise `dd` will report that `/dev/disk1` is busy.